# How do I specify smart tags for my control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, controls, smart-tags

If I am creating a custom ASP.NET control (or, I suppose, a Windows Forms control), how do I specify one or more Smart Tags for it, and the behavior that goes with it? I want to provide some rich designer support.

EDIT: Prefer C# code, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/32650/0/page/3).